# Is it ever appropriate to set the prototype to an instance of another constructor function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

It is more common to see the following as a kind of inheritance:

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
B.prototype = A.prototype;
```

But is the following ever appropriate? If so, for what use cases?

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
B.prototype = new A();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is unusual.  A instances and B instances would have the exact same inheritance hierarchy.  It would be equivalent to having two different constructors for the same class.

The second usage would be more typical, I think.  It is pretty much what Node.js does when you use util.inherits, for example.

**Update for modern JS (ES6):**

You shouldn't use `new A()`, but rather `Object.create(A.prototype)`.  When you use `new A()`, something happens which you *don't* want: you are calling the `A` constructor once globally even if no `A` or `B` instances are ever created.  You should already be calling the `A` parent constructor in the `B` constructor.  Calling an extra time is pointless and sometimes might not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one `B.prototype = A.prototype;` , you are making them the same object so the change to A will also change B.
Second one `B.prototype = new A();` is how you do inheritance with prototypes by making the B an instance of A.

Answer (score 0):

There are other answers, but one reason might be this:

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
function C() {}

B.prototype = new A();
C.prototype = new A();
```